# Choix entre l'infinitif passé et l'infinitif présent dans une subordonnée

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, indications-de-temps, subordonnées

J'aurais besoin de votre aide avec un petit exercice. Il faut récrire la phrase suivante au passé et faire les accords si nécessaire :

> Elle se lave les dents puis se brosse les cheveux avant de se mettre du rouge aux lèvres.

J'ai écrit deux solutions :

a) Elle s'est lavé les dents puis s'est brossé les cheveux avant de **se mettre** du rouge aux lèvres.

b) Elle s'est lavé les dents puis s'est brossé les cheveux avant de **s'être mis** du rouge aux lèvres.

Laquelle est correcte ?

Comment: Faut-il conformer à l'usage préscrit ou courant?

Comment: Préscrit, je pense... Donc les deux sont possibles, mais b) est préscrit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ta question porte manifestement sur le choix à faire entre un infinitif présent (se mettre) et un infinitif passé (*s'être mis*).

L'infinitif passé s'utilisera si l'action exprimée est antérieure à une autre action. Ce que, dans cette phrase, *avant de* contredirait.

On aurait effectivement pu le concevoir suite à un *après*

Soit : *elle s'est lavé les dents avant **de se mettre** du rouge aux lèvres mais après **s'être mis** un collier.*